# SED remove new line lines containing a pattern

Tags: awk, sed

I want to remove (sed or awk) the newline on all the lines that contains just one time the character " but once the newline has been removed on the line it can be remove on the following line.

this is an example

```
line1"test 2015"
line2"test
2015"
line3"test 2020"
line4"test
2017"
```

should be transformed in:

```
line1"test 2015"
line2"test2015"
line3"test 2020"
line4"test2017"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Using GNU awk:

```
awk -v RS='"' 'NR % 2 == 0 { gsub(/\n/, ""); } { printf("%s%s", $0, RT) }' filename
```

This is the most straightforward way. Using `"` as the record separator,

```
NR % 2 == 0 {             # in every other record (those inside quotes)
  gsub(/\n/, "")          # remove the newlines
}
{ 
  printf("%s%s", $0, RT)  # then print the line terminated by the same thing
                          # as in the input (to avoid an extra quote at the
                          # end of the output)
}
```

`RT` is a GNU extension, that's why this requires gawk.

#### Using sed

The difficulty in doing this with sed is the possibility that there may be two newlines between quotes, such as

```
line2"test
123
2015"
```

This makes fetching just a single line after the condition brittle. Therefore:

```
sed '/^[^"]*"[^"]*$/ { :a /\n.*"/! { N; ba; }; s/\n//g; }' filename
```

That is:

```
/^[^"]*"[^"]*$/ {   # When a line contains only one quote
  :a                # jump label for looping
  /\n.*"/! {        # until there appears another quote
    N               # fetch more lines
    ba
  }
  s/\n//g           # once done, remove the newlines.
}
```

As a one-liner, this requires GNU sed because BSD sed is picky about the formatting of branch instructions. It should, however, be possible to put the expanded form of the code into a file, say `foo.sed`, and run `sed -f foo.sed filename` with BSD sed.

Note that this code assumes that after an opening quote, the next line with a quote in it contains only that one quote. A way around that problem, if required, is

```
sed ':a h; s/[^"]//g; s/""//g; /"/ { x; N; s/\n//; ba }; x' filename
```

...but that is arguably beyond the scope of things that should reasonably be done with sed. It works like this:

```
:a           # jump label for looping
h            # make a copy of the line
s/[^"]//g    # isolate quotes
s/""//g      # remove pairs of quotes
/"/ {        # if there is a quote left (number of quotes is odd)
  x          # swap the unedited text back into the pattern space
  N          # fetch a new line
  s/\n//     # remove the newline between them
  ba         # loop
}
x            # swap the text back in before printing.
```

#### Using non-GNU awk

The case of several quotes per line is easier to handle in awk than in sed. The GNU awk code above does it implicitly; for non-GNU awk it takes a little more doing (but not terribly so):

```
awk -F '"' '{ n = 0; line = ""; do { n += NF != 0 ? NF - 1 : 0; line = line $0 } while(n % 2 == 1 && getline == 1) print line }' filename
```

The main trick is to use `"` as field separator so that the number of fields tells us how many quotes are in the line. Then:

```
{
                                       # reset state
  n = 0                                # n is the number of quotes we have
                                       # seen so far
  line = ""                            # line is where we assemble the output
                                       # line

  do {
    n += NF != 0 ? NF - 1 : 0;         # add the number of quotes in the line
                                       # (special handling for empty lines
                                       # where NF == 0)
    line = line $0                     # append the line to the output
  } while(n % 2 == 1 && getline == 1)  # while the number of quotes is odd
                                       # and there's more input, get new lines
                                       # and loop

  print line                           # once done, print the combined result.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

With sed:

```
sed '/[^"]$/{N;s/\n//}' file
```

Output:

```
line1"test 2015"
line2"test2015"
line3"test 2020"
line4"test2017"
```

Search (`//`) for lines not (`^`) end (`$`) with single character `"`. Only for these lines (`{}`): append next line (`N`) to sed's pattern space (current line) and use sed's search and replace (`s///`) to find in pattern space the now embedded newline (`\n`) and replace by nothing.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r ':a;N;s/^([^\n"]*"[^\n"]*)\n/\1 /;ta;P;D' file
```

This replaces the newline between two lines with a space where the first line only contains one double quote.

N.B. the space may be removed as well but the data suggested it.